# Unable to create Read replica - AWS RDS SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a read replica for a Sql Server enterprise Edition (2016 SP2 CU16) but no such option is presented in the drop down. I have gone through all the documentation provided and the instance conforms with all the conditions like being an EE and above the min required version etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYZeC.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYl6V.png

Comment: That screenshot you’ve provided are not where you would configure this. It’s within the AG wizard during initial setup, or AG properties; for each replica, after setup.

Comment: Based on your screen shot your instance is using mirroring for the multi az double check that there is no option to change that to Availability Groups